# Why does the following loop not break - Python?

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to print the results of cmd **ping google.com**, which should output 9 lines in total then stop.

```
Pinging google.com [216.58.208.46] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.58.208.46: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=55
Reply from 216.58.208.46: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=55
Reply from 216.58.208.46: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=55
Reply from 216.58.208.46: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=55

Ping statistics for 216.58.208.46:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 27ms, Maximum = 28ms, Average = 27ms
```

After running my script below

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ping','www.google.com'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
  line = proc.stdout.readline()
  if line != '':
    print("line:", line)
  else:
    break
```

I see the dynamically printed cmd results line by like, however after the last line is printed, my loop carries on printing forever, like the following

```
line: b'Pinging www.google.com [216.58.208.36] with 32 bytes of data:\r\n'
line: b'Reply from 216.58.208.36: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=56\r\n'
line: b'Reply from 216.58.208.36: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=56\r\n'
line: b'Reply from 216.58.208.36: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=56\r\n'
line: b'Reply from 216.58.208.36: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=56\r\n'
line: b'\r\n'
line: b'Ping statistics for 216.58.208.36:\r\n'
line: b'    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),\r\n'
line: b'Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:\r\n'
line: b'    Minimum = 26ms, Maximum = 27ms, Average = 26ms\r\n'
line: b''
line: b''
line: b''
line: b''
line: b''
line: b''
line: b''
line: b''
line: b''
...
```

I am wondering if my loop is carrying on because of this mysteriuos **b** character, but where is this **b** character coming from after **line:**?

modifying

```
    print("line:", line)
```

to

```
    print("line:", line[1:])
```

returns

```
line: b'inging www.google.com [216.58.208.36] with 32 bytes of data:\r\n'
line: b'eply from 216.58.208.36: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=56\r\n'
line: b'eply from 216.58.208.36: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=56\r\n'
line: b'eply from 216.58.208.36: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=56\r\n'
```

not removing the **b** character.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `if str(line) != '':`, that might help you

Comment: @BryanMoyles Why would that help? `readline` returns a string already.

Comment: An empty byte string `b''` isn't equal to an empty string `''`... just use `if line`...

Comment: Using python 2.7 onward i am not getting the 'b' character.

Answer (score 5):

replace

```
if line != '':
```

with

```
if line:
```

After the output is finished it doesn't produce a `''`. It is therefore easier to check whether an output equates to `True` or `False`.

This works well in Python as empty strings, lists, tuples, dictionaries etc, as well as the number `0` and the value `None`, all equate to `False` when used in the above manner.

In regards to the `b` character, that denotes that what you are receiving is a byte string, instead of a normal string. You can't remove the `b` using slicing in the same way you can't remove the `[]` brackets from a list using slicing.

To get rid of the b you'll need to `decode` your string.

Comment: but what if a cmd line outputted the number 0, wouldnt that be valid output which would evaluate to false? we need that being evaluated as true.

Comment: `bool(b'0') == True`. Only empty sequences are falsy. `bool(b"") == False`

Comment: @ImranPatel, `readline` always returns a (byte) **string**, not a number.  The string `b'0'` is **not** "the number 0" and does **not** evaluate to false -- it evaluates to true since it's a non-empty string!

Comment: @HakenLid, that's because you're analysing a string, not an int. `bool(0) == False` and `bool(int(b'0')) == False`. Python doesn't do implicit conversion.

Comment: @ImranPatel, and as for changing the byte strings into text, `print` `line.decode('ascii')` or whatever other encoding the byte string is using (you do have to know or guess the encoding).

Answer (score 0):

As you use `print()` and output begins with `b`, I assume you are using a Python 3.x. In Python 3.x, a string is made of unicode chars , whereas `bytes` and `bytearray`s are made of bytes (8 bits). The initial `b` just says that `line` is in fact a `bytes` object.

Your test should then be either `if str(line) != '':` or `if line != b'':`, because `'' == b''` returns `False` because they are objects of different classes.

Comment: *are made of 8 bytes* - what kind of futuristic super computer are you using? :) (think you mean bits)

Comment: Oups ! I should I read what I have written with more attention ! Thanks for noticing ...

Answer (score 0):

Since this is Python, this loop does what you want and is more readable:

```
for line in proc.stdout:
    print(line)
```